# call operator<< on temporary

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qxqb9M)):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

using namespace std::string_literals;

template<class CharT, class Traits>
void test(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &s) {
    s << "Other test\n"s;
}

struct my_struct {
    std::string s = "My Struct\n"s;
};

template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &stream,
                                              const my_struct &s) {
    stream << s.s;
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    fs::path file("test.txt");
    const my_struct s;

    // A
    operator<<(std::ofstream(file, std::ios_base::app), "Other test!\n"s);   // Runs fine
    std::ofstream(file, std::ios_base::app) << "Das ist ein Test!\n"s;       // Runs fine

    // B
    operator<<(std::ofstream(file, std::ios_base::app), s);                  // Runs fine
    std::ofstream(file, std::ios_base::app) << s;                            // Runs fine

    // C
    // test(std::ofstream(file, std::ios_base::app));                        // Does not compile
}
```

The code parts A and B compile just fine, while C does not. It is clear that `test` cannot take an rvalue since the argument is a non-`const` reference.

But shouldn't `A` and `B` be the same? Both the `operator<<` of the STL and my own one take the left-hand-side as a non-`const` reference. So why is it possible for them to work with a temporary object?

Compiler:

```
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

EDIT: First version of the question had a bug, that made the own `operator<<` segfault.

Comment: Just use rvalue like that `void test(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &&s)`

Comment: The last `s` in this line is a typo? `s << "Other test\n"s;` (Nothing to do with the problem, though.)

Comment: @Manuel no that is a string literal. I wanted to use std::string since builtin types are sometimes handled differently (basic_ostream has a member operator<< for those).

Comment: @Kitsu I am aware how one could work around that. But I am interested in why it works for the operator<<'s, since it goes against my understanding of c++.

Comment: @n314159 Ouch! Yes. I didn't use those very often and I forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why is it possible for them to work with a temporary object?

Because, unlike your `operator <<`, some from the standard library are not free, but [*member* functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) which can readily work on temporary objects without any problem, while the non-member functions have an [explicit overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) taking rvalue (or more precise, forward)-references.

Comment: Ah, I knew that there are some member functions, that's why I used string as right operand, the member functions are only defined for a few builtin types. I missed the rvalue overload, that explains it. On the cppref page there is also a link to LWG issue that requests the overload: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203